# Here Maps: check if a Polygon contains a Point?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there built in function to check if a Point is inside a Polygon?

Google Maps:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point.latLng, polygon)
```

Yandex Maps:

```
polygon.geometry.contains(point.geometry.getCoordinates())
```

Here Maps:

```
?
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find of scouring through the JavaScript API, there doesn't appear to be a way to determine whether a Point exists inside a Polygon from just the JS API itself.

However, because you can get a GeoJSON Feature object from the Here Maps polygon, you can use a third-party library such as [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) (in particular, the [`booleanPointInPolygon` method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon)) to find whether a particular Point is contained in a Polygon.

```js
// This checks to see whether the Sydney Harbour Bridge is contained somewhere in Sydney
poly = new H.map.Polygon(new H.geo.LineString([150.64, -34.08, 0, 150.64, -33.53, 0, 151.33, -33.53, 0, 151.33, -34.08, 0]),
    {
        style: { fillColor: 'rgba(150, 100, 0, .8)', lineWidth: 0 }
    }
)

point = new H.geo.Point(151.21, -33.84);

console.log(turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point.toGeoJSON(), poly.toGeoJSON())) // true
```

Answer (score -1):

For simple use case, you can use Turfjs.org library.
For more complex cases, use HERE Fleet Telematics Geofencing, see developer.here.com